# Eclipse ADT ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm brand new to eclipse and android and I'm trying to follow tutorials but every time I create a new project it has a bunch of extra stuff that the tutorials don't have. Instead of extending Activity it extends ActionBarActivity and starts with extra methods that I don't think I need. Is there a way to create a new project without the action bar stuff?

Comment: You should 99% of the time start with an actionbar project, use more up to date tutorials.

Comment: jst create the a blank project.

Comment: Just have a look at this.It would help you

here's the [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369992/android-adt-bundle-automatically-extending-actionbaractivity-and-adding-fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want ActionBar activity, then replace the class with this code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```