# android adt bundle automatically extending ActionBarActivity and adding fragments and more stuff?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I just want to make a simple Hello world app that extends Activity but when I create a new android project it add all this extra stuff. It didn't use to do it before,but now everytime I create a project it extends ActionBarActivity and creates a fragment layout and has code for fragments and its no longer the simple project I used to be able to create.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I too had the same problem and this is how I fixed it.

When you create new Android Application Project, select Minimum Required SDK as API 14 or above.

[image]

If you want to support API level < 14 you can change the "minSdkVersion" in AndroidManifest.xml manually after creating the project.

Comment: Got rid of the errors but not the inclusion of the fragment. When did the API change? Is this a KitKat thing?