# Creating a basic Android Project now adds a Fragment Layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is weird. I had recently gotten into Android programming. I made a fresh install but when I create a new project there is this new option called Fragment Layout Name at the very end of the page where you specify your Activity name. I haven't had this happen before but when I open my main activity this is what I get. Also half of it is filled with errors according to Android. Is there anyway I can go back and avoid this?

```
package com.example.quizactivity;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe it's an API version thing. I am about to try suggestion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369992/android-adt-bundle-automatically-extending-actionbaractivity-and-adding-fragment#

Comment: Will take a look at that. This thing has been driving me nuts I haven't even learned much about Fragments. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it really is a mess. I wish they created the initial code in this fashion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840509/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default-simple-fr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do as follows, this works for me..**

```
Step-1:
```

Right Click on your Project -> Properties -> Android -> In Library panel, **remove** appcompat_v7 library, Apply and Ok

```
Step-2:
```

In Project goto res -> values -> style.xml

In line `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">` **change** parent value from `Theme.AppCompat.Light` to `android:Theme.Light`

```
Step-3:
```

In Project goto res -> values-v11 -> style.xml

In line `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">` **change** parent value from `Theme.AppCompat.Light` to `android:Theme.Holo.Light`

```
Step-4:
```

In Project goto res -> values-v14 -> style.xml

In line `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` **change** parent value from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`

```
Step-5:
```

In Project goto menu -> main.xml **remove** these lines in menu tag:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity"
```

and in item tag **change** this line from `app:showAsAction="never"` to `android:showAsAction="never"`

In project, goto res -> layout -> **delete fragment.xml**

```
Step-6:
```

In MainActivity **extends Activity** not ActionBarActivity and finally your MainActivity.java after **remove unnecessary code**, looks like this:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**Enjoy:)**

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new project Select Minimum SDK version as upper or higher as u can . and then u will get rid of app compact .
I have chosen Miminum SDK 4.0 and get rid of it .