# Create New Activity adds an activity which extends Activity class instead of ActionBarActivity class in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, adt, eclipse-adt

I am a newbie to android and I was following the tutorial on [android.developer.com](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html),Where a new Activity creation adds an activity which extends ActionBarActivity by default,but When i 
create a new Activity it extends Activity class by default

I have also tried to set the Min API to 4.1 Jelly Bean and target to 4.4 as ActionBarActivity is available in later API but it didn't work,I have  downloaded the Adt bundle from the site

Answer (score 0):

When you create new project in eclipse, you should select min required SDK below 14 to extend from ActionBarActivity.
Check this: [android adt bundle automatically extending ActionBarActivity and adding fragments and more stuff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369992/android-adt-bundle-automatically-extending-actionbaractivity-and-adding-fragment/22370547#22370547)