# New Blank Activity extends ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I have a strange "problem" on my Android Studio 0.9.9, and still on the version 1.

Since this update, when i create a new project android studio doesn't create a blank activity. It should be "MainActivity extends Activity", but it's "MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity"

I have a second problem as well. When i'm editing Layout Files, on the Preview of the Layout, i can't see the ActionBar (But i don't have this problem when i'm editing previous project)

I really don't know where this problem is coming from. Maybe a problem in the configuration of Android Studio, but i didn't change anything. Or maybe it's just some new features.

I'm new in Android Development so it might be my lack of knowledge.

Has Someone had this problem before ? Any hint or advice on this?

Is my explanation lucid?

Thanks for your help !

EDIT :

After some search, i found some post from StackOverflow :

- [By default android creating new project as ActionBarActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516578/by-default-android-creating-new-project-as-actionbaractivity)
- [Create New Activity adds an activity which extends Activity class instead of ActionBarActivity class in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578807/create-new-activity-adds-an-activity-which-extends-activity-class-instead-of-act)
- [android adt bundle automatically extending ActionBarActivity and adding fragments and more stuff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369992/android-adt-bundle-automatically-extending-actionbaractivity-and-adding-fragment/22370547#22370547)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update May 4th, 2015:

Starting with Support Library 22.1 ([blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html)):

> In this release, `ActionBarActivity` has been deprecated in favor of the new `AppCompatActivity`.

#### Original Post:

> Has Someone had this problem before ? Any hint or advice on this?

This is not a problem but intended to help you apply the new design language by Google, named [Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html). One major change is the new UI widget called Toolbar. To use it you have to extend from `ActionBarActivity` as mentioned in a [recent blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) by the Android developers. In this blog post you will also find more information about the Toolbar widget.

So if you're new, Google is just trying to help you to get right on track with the new elements and styles.

Answer (score 0):

In your `resources` xml file, your `Action Bar` style should have a parent. Something like:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.THE_STYLE_YOU_WANT"> //HoloDark, MaterialLight, ect
    <item name="android:background">custom color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Ryan

you're talking about the styles.xml ? But no i don't have any parent.

My problem is like a wrong configuration in Android Studio, and not from my project. Because every single new project i can create, i have the same problem on any of them.

Comment: Yes, and every project you create auto creates code that may be missing information. The templates are far from perfect

Answer (score 0):

i also feel strange for that it extends the actionbaractivity,some days before when i create a project and set minsdk to 14,**it extends activity and use holo theme when under lollipop** ,but today i do the same thing and found **it didn't derive from the activity and use the appcompat theme only**,indeed one new feature for appcompat library is that it **Added support for material design user interfaces.** maybe extends actionbaractivity is for the sake of using the newest theme,because under lollipop you can't use material theme,use appcompat is the quickest way, i don't know google's manner for the holo theme now.

Comment: Thanks for your andwer Cajsaiko.

I think you're right !

Then i will put this post as "solved"